# Endless loop in cron job php

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have to send bulk emails to the users. I think of having an endless loop in a cron job, where I want to fetch a few dozens or hundreds users and send emails one by one - updating the the table, that the email was sent. And also I should put some sleep interval, as soon as each packet of dozen(or hundred) users received the email. Basically it looks like

```
while(1 != 0) {
$notifications = // fetch notifications, where email is not sent

foreach($notifications as $notification) {
    // 1) send email
    // 2) update table - email was sent
}

sleep(5);
}
```

Now, is this all right to use, or it is considered a bad practice ?

I know, I can also use multiple crons, lets say every one minute, but to prevent overlapping  when using lock file, as soon as the cron starts and the lock file exists(so another cron is still running) it should either

```
a) wait for some time to the first cron to finish, to start, 
or 
b) just return empty, allowing the next cron to do the job ASA the ongoing one is done.
```

The problem with `a)` is that, what if the crons take lot more time than expected, then after some time I will have bunch of crons in a "waiting" state. About the `b)` case, what if immediately after the second cron is done(returning empty), the first cron ends, so I will have a gap of ~ one minute, and I need to send emails to users as soon as possible.

also, qsn 2, what is better in performance wise, one cron in loop vs multiple crons?

Thanks

Comment: I personally dont think having an endless loop in a cron job is a good idea.  Crons are meant for tasks that need to be repeated at a specific time or time interval, so what happens the next time your cron job fires?

Comment: @watcher, thanks for the comment, good point ! but it seems there is a solution for that http://serverfault.com/questions/111609/how-to-run-a-cron-job-only-once

Comment: Whats it goto do with the mysql tag?, anyways personally id make an [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) daemon for this, [[Example, Run PHP script as daemon process](http://icodes.it/blog/Run-PHP-script-as-daemon-process)], because of the inf loop, it will be much cleaner, and not have multiple running instances.

Comment: As mentionned by @watcher crons are for periodical tasks, what you need is a daemon (i don't know if PHP is a good fit for that, some reading http://kvz.io/blog/2009/01/09/create-daemons-in-php/)

Comment: Speaking of performance, why update the table after each email is sent? If you send 1000 emails, you don't want to do 1000 queries. Store an array of ids of all those updated, and just update them all in 1 query when you're done?

Comment: @MLeFevre, yeah I thought about that, it definitely would be better with one query, but what I was afraid of, that if something happens after sending 999 emails and the cron job stops or smth, then the statues won't be updated, so next time these users will get email again, which should not happen. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing a daemon, not a cron task.

There are lots of daemons that run continuously, so no, it's not a bad practice to do that.

If you want the daemon automatically restarted if it crashes, you could have a watchdog task, which continuously checks that the daemon is running, and starts a daemon process if one isn't running.

Another alternative (as you describe) is to have crontask that occasionally attempts to start the daemon; the startup should detect whether the daemon process is already running. If it's already running, leave it be, and just exit. If it's not running, then start another one (in the background, as a detached process.  Either way, the crontask completes quickly.

(And it doesn't matter one whit whether the daemon connects to MySQL.)

Comment: thanks for the answer, (@Loz Cherone ツ also mentioned in comment) I did not know about daemon, will take a look and give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I dislike endless loops. I prefer a *cron job* running every **5 minutes** for example.
And you can optimize your script for send max emails quantity in cron job time.

You need to estimate how many emails you will send per minute. I'll assume **1 email per second**.

So my idea is:

1. Query for **290** notifications [10 seconds delay to get and update notifications] and mark them as "*sending*" status (to prevent next cron dont pick them).
2. Send emails and save result in array (for later update).
3. When finished, update notifications status (sent or error).

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks man for the answer, the point is I cant estimate email sending, what if there is a long delay on same of them, maybe some email servers are down or have a late response time

Comment: Ok, then you should 'play safe' and send 1 email every 5 seconds for example. Only change your LIMIT condition (on query).
But this isnt your real problem. I think the main thing is overlapping cron jobs. With my solution, you havent that problem.

Comment: setting the status as pending have some issues IMO. First, if the cron job stops for some reason, the email with "sending" status will never be sent again, secondly it is one more extra query for updating the status to "sending". Thanks

Comment: You can improve your first query, selecting by last 1 hour with status 'sending' first:
SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE (status = 'sending' AND created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) OR (status = 'ready') LIMIT 100
For better performance, replace status by foreign key and add some indexes.